# AutoIt fill form in Firefox - read and write to CSV

Tags: csv, autoit

Do anyone have an example code of autoIt?

I want to change from iMacros to autoIt and I need an example code of how to read from CSV file, fill form in Firefox and write the solution to a CSV.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a:

1. [CSV UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/38397-csv-udf/)
2. [Firefox UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/95595-ffau3-v0601b-10/)

You can find UDFs and examples on those links.

Answer (score 1):

For reading a file you can use `FileRead(...)`, for splitting up the data you can use `StringSplit(...)`:

```
$CVSFile = FileRead("ThisIsMyCVSFile.txt")
If @error Then MsgBox(0, "", @error)
$splitCVS = StringSplit($CVSFile, ",", 1)
MsgBox(0, "", $splitCVS[1])   // make a For-loop from 0 to splitcvs[0]
```

Also, I'm not sure on what you want to fill in in Firefox, but here is an example:

```
$id = ""
ControlSend("Mozilla Firefox Start Page - Mozilla Firefox", "", $id, "This is what I want to send")
```

Replace the `$id` variable with the ID of the "form" you want to write to.